# how can I merge two web projects in one solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a web project in visual studio. for example my web site and another web project in visual studio. for example admin panel

I want to merge these two projects in one solution and run example

first project's address is `localhost:1953/Default.aspx`
second project's address is `localhost:1953/Management/Default.aspx`

I'm trying add existing project to solution and run but second project address is changing..

Comment: what do you mean by 'keeps changing'?  whats it supposed to be, and what do you get instead?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Could you please explain more specific. so that someone can help you

Comment: port address are different of two project when I want to run. I want to work as a single project.

Comment: port will always be different for different projects, as a separate iis dev app is being activated for each project. if you want the port to be the same, you do not 'merge' projects into one solution, you will need to merge them in to one ***Project***, meaning you move all the files from one project to another and adjust your default pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By address change, I am imagining that you mean your port is changing.

Your port is always going to change in separate projects because IIS creates a new port for each one.  You cannot have them run on the same port.